# How to Run a Custom update query in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

Is it possible to run a custom update query in codeigniter. I need to run following query in codeigniter,

```
UPDATE `category` SET `online`= IF(online=1,0,1) WHERE id = 10
```

it is checking online value before update. if online = 1 then 0,if online = 0 then 1. I tested and query is working perfect, but how can I run this query in codeigniter.

Comment: use `$this->db->query( $your_query )` on model

Comment: yp it is working

Comment: Actually, for simplicity reason, I prefer use this. We can test query, then just copy it to model :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
    $updateData = array(
        'online' => IF(online=1,0,1)
    );
    $this->db->where('id', 10);
    $this->db->update('category', $updateData);
```

Comment: can t put `'online' => IF(online=1,0,1)`  it s getting error

Comment: out it in single quotes `online' =>'IF(online=1,0,1)'`

Comment: Maybe correct this unexplained answer to fix the missing quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like *Nishant Nair* mentioned, or you can use pure SQL like:

```
$this->db->query('YOUR SQL QUERY HERE');
```

Also take a look at documentation:
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#updating-data

Answer (score 0):

```
    $updateData = array(
        'col1' => 999
    );
    $this->db->set("online","IF(online=1,0,1)",false); //set false third parameter to prevent from auto escaping
    $this->db->where('id', 10);
    $this->db->update('category', $updateData);
```

You can use the `set` command in codeigniter db query helper.Still you can use the `updateData array` in `update` command 2nd parameter if ever you need more `set` of fields